# Show popup on the map for the selected item in the side list using the mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, mapbox

I followed this tutorial ["Filter features within map view"](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/) and managed to adapt it to my data, which are polygons instead of points.

However, the popups on the side menu are not displayed, when I place the mouse over one of the locations, the popup does not appear on the map indicating the location as it should.
The problem I believe is that because it is a polygon and not a point (a pair of coordinates) the code cannot display the location, the error in the console is:

```
"Uncaught Error:` LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, an object {lon: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>] "
```

In the map popup I changed it from "`.setLngLat (feature.geometry.coordinates)`"
to "`.setLngLat (e.lngLat)`" and it worked, but not in the popup on the side menu.
I'm still starting to learn javascript and I couldn't find a solution, I thought about extracting the centroid from the polygon, but I don't know how to do it.

the code that generates the popup:

```
var prop = feature.properties;
var item = document.createElement('a');
item.href = prop.wikipedia;
item.target = '_blank';
item.textContent = prop.NM_UF + ' (' + prop.SIGLA_UF + ')';
item.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    // Highlight corresponding feature on the map
    popup
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setText(
            feature.properties.NM_UF +
            ' (' +
            feature.properties.SIGLA_UF +
            ')'
        )
        .addTo(map);
});
listingEl.appendChild(item);
    });
```

Here is a codepen like the code:
https://codepen.io/hugonbgg/pen/PoNwWVj and the debug: https://codepen.io/hugonbgg/debug/PoNwWVj/